# What you need to make a 3D game in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm Very confused with what i need to make a 3D game like Morrowind or Fable. I've spent a lot of time surfing Google and do not understand some of the terms used... like IED. I have installed Code::Blocks for my compiler and it doesn't look very promising..... It looks like i need a lot more to make a game... What do i need to make one?  Please make it simple and Understandable. I have heard about Unity but a really want to make it from the ground. Thank You!

Comment: "really want to make it from the ground" - are you sure? That's going to be a lot of work to just get the very basics up-and-running. Which isn't to say it's not a worthwhile learning experience, but it'd be a lot of work you don't really have to do.

Comment: I think you're asking for something like DirectX  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh309467(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I've been programming for 11 years now and I would find making a game like Morrowind or Fable from the ground up an impossible task. If you don't know what an IDE is, be prepared to spend a loooooong time making your game.

Comment: OP is trying to make an IED? Uh oh, where's the NSA when you need them...

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also keep in mind that the games you mention (and virtually every other game on the market) use game engines for their core.  Making a game engine, while still a substantial task, is much less daunting that a full-fledged production-quality game.  There are some books that will walk you through creating a simple game engine (some even with a basic scripting engine built in) ... or you can use something like the Unreal Engine (which is free to download for academic purposes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People here aren't quite giving you the right answers, so I'll straighten things up. Making a game is the easiest thing you can imagine. You just have to do the following:

- Make a game engine,
- use it to make your game.

While people here are telling you that:

> What you need to make a game like Morrowind or Fable is (a) some programming experience, (b) another fifty people with skills in programming, design and art, (c) a few million pounds and (d) 18-24 months.

and

> I've been programming for 11 years now and I would find making a game like Morrowind or Fable from the ground up an impossible task.

And they're partly right. All the time and money mentioned comes from the first step of the process - designing and making a game engine.

If you want to start designing an engine, you have to:

- Posses intermediate knowledge of the programming language,
- Know how and where to search resources,
- Have wide knowledge concerning computer graphics,
- Spend most of your time reading books and designing your engine.

If you want facts, then here it goes: designing a simple game engine, that focuses on one type of games will take you approximately 1.5 years. If you know what you're doing and you're working alone of course. That's at least what it took me to make a tower defense game engine from scratch, using OpenGL and GLUT.

And a good advice: at the point you're currently in - **don't try**. First try doing something using *Multimedia Fusion*, then - when you understand the basic logic - start using *Unity*, *Ogre3D*, *Panda3D* or *Unreal Developer Kit*. Then - if you actually get to that part - think if you **need** to do anything from scratch, and only then **do it**.

Comment: I wouldn't state a hard time frame as it can vary greatly depending on the goals and abilities of the developer, but the rest of the answer is good info.

Comment: Added "approximately" if it wasn't as clear as it should :) I had no knowledge of game engine structure when I started (I had a degree in graphic design tho), so I think that even an intermediate developer with that knowledge shouldn't work much longer.

Answer (score 4):

Making a game link Morrowind or Fable is really difficult and time consuming.
And doing something like that alone is out of the question. It's usually teams of people working on projects like that.

Instead, start with something simpler. Use a library like SFML or SDL to handle a lot of the work for you and make a small puzzle game or something small. With experience comes the ability to do more and more!

Answer (score 2):

To make something like Morrowind, you need a good development team of about 35 people consisting of programmers, environmental, graphic and other artists, (plot) writers, quest designers, voice actors, PR & marketing manager as well as a good sales man, and about 6 years to make a first release. Once you have all of that, you can pretty much code your game in any suitable language, be that C++, C, Objective-C or whatever other language of your choice.

If you really want to make a game, I recommend you read some books on game development and start by using existing [gaming engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines). I am not from game dev industry, but I am sure good people from https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ would be able to recommend you a lot of good books as well as advise on how to start.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!